# Python Requests Proxy 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, proxy, python-requests

**I am trying to do a request using a Proxy.**

My Code:

```
import requests
proxies = {'http' '1.1.1.1:1234'}
r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip', proxies=proxies)
print(r.text)
```

The Error:

```
    no_proxy = proxies.get('no_proxy') if proxies is not None else None
    AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'get'
```

**Edit:**

I missed a `:`.

New Code:

```
import requests
proxies = {'http': '1.1.1.1:1234'}
r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip', proxies=proxies)
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a `:` in your dictionary:

```
proxies = {'http': '1.1.1.1:1234'}
```

If you have `proxies = {'http' '1.1.1.1:1234'}`, then `proxies` is actually a `set` with the single value of `'http1.1.1.1:1234'`, hence the error.